# My jQuery hide/view function works but does not if executed through another script

Tags: php, jquery

I've made a function to hide/view my category menu:

The script:

```
      function toggle(id) {

         var e = document.getElementById(id);
         if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
         else
            e.style.display = 'block';
      }

      </script>
```

I use it on a p tag like this:

```
     <p onclick="toggle('foos');";>Category</p>
```

The above works perfectly. When I click on "Category" it shows or hide my div.

However I then made another menu as a list. I want to execute my "toggle" function when you click on one of the "li" from my list.

I've tried to do that with this:

```
    $(".uldropdown").on('click','li',function (){

    $("#displaytwo .menu p").click();

    });
```

But when I click on one of the "li" it shows my category menu only for a split second and then it immediately disappears.

So it almost works, but for some reason the div disappears immediately right after the click. I hope someone can tell me whats wrong. Thank you

Edit:
**This is my list menu:**

```
     echo '<div id="foo">';
     echo '<ul id="uldropdown" class="uldropdown">

     <ul>';


   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<li  class="lidropdown">'.$row['name'].'</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>
   </ul></div>';
```

**My category menu:**

```
      <div class="hejsa" >
      <p onclick="toggle('foos');";>Category</p>

      <?php
        echo '
        <div id="foos">';

         echo '<ul id="catdropdown" class="catdropdown">

              <ul>';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcats)) {
            echo '<li  class="catdropdown" onclick="location.reload()"; ">'.$row['category'].'</li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>
        </ul></div></div>';
```

I did not add some of the SQL parts, just to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: `when I click on one of the "li" it shows my category menu only for a split second and then it immediately disappears` this sounds like the `click` event you're faking is propagating up the DOM and being caught by the `onclick` attribute and closing itself again. Can you please add your HTML to the question. As an aside, you really shouldn't be using `on*` event attributes any more. Use unobtrusive event handlers in all places, as in your second code example

Comment: I have added the html parts. I don't understand "propagating up the DOM". I will have to read up on "DOM" and return back. jQuery is very new to me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan appreciate the help. I have to head out so wont be responding before I'm back home again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ``$(document).on();`` is still necessary where ``.click`` isn't able to see dynamically generated elements. Freddy, it would be very helpful if you were able to include your code in the question as a "snippet" so we can see what you're seeing. You'll need to exchange the PHP code for templated/dummy data. You can learn about how to do snippets here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @GrantNoe You've misunderstood. When I said you shouldn't use `on*` event attributes I'm talking about literal HTML attributes such as `onclick`, `onhover` etc, not jQuery methods.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah, I see what you're referencing -- agreed.